# Regex ruby not match strings with capital letters - accented characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, postgresql

I am writing a regex to match only strings not containing any capital letters, any number or some special characters. So far, I managed to match strings without capital letters but the accented capital letters are still matched.

```
Word.where.not("content ~* ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*")
```

The content column is a string of a word. Eg. "car", "Anatolia", "Érevan".

I want to match: "Érevan", "aNaTOLa", "J-core" but not "car" or "city-council".

Any idea which regex is appropriate? I tried to use `:upper:` but I guess I am doing something wrong as it's not working. Thanks.

Comment: Try `"([0-9])|([.,?!])|^\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*"`

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected matches. Also, `~*` looks like SQL, not Ruby. Please provide more detail.

Comment: WiktorStribiżew it matches words with capital letters. @Amadan : I added the full rails request.

Comment: I presume it is PostgreSQL? If so, please additionally tag as [tag:postgresql], as this query is not executed by Ruby, and per rules of [tag:regex] tag, the engine or dialect of regex needs to be tagged in addition to [tag:regex]. Furthermore, `content` is a column name; we don't know what is in there, and what you want to match. Please provide examples (not just descriptions) of things you do want to match, and things you do not.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan I just added the examples and tag.

Comment: "to match only strings not containing any capital letters", but "Anatolia" should match? Do you mean "starting with a capital letter", as visible in your `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*`?

Comment: I want to match any string containing a capital letter, even accented (at the start or in the middle of the word).

Comment: `^\p{Lu}\p{L}*$` [works fine](https://rubular.com/r/eSINW1DVKfqd3N) in Ruby, it won't work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried the following but it doesn't work, maybe because of Postgres? `Word.where.not("content ~* ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^\p{Lu}\p{L}*$")`

Comment: POSIX character classes are usually Unicode aware. Are you sure `Word.where.not("content ~* ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*$")` does not work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is better, but still "J-core" is not matched as it's not followed by alphanumerical character :/

Comment: Aha, so there can be any char but whitespace? Try `Word.where.not("content ~ ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[[:upper:]]\S*$"`. Or, if there can be letters or hyphen, `Word.where.not("content ~ ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]-]*$")`

Comment: Also note that `~*` is case-insensitive matching; I believe you have to use `~` for `[[:upper:]]` to be meaningful. Also, by your current examples, it seems you just want to match if there is an uppercase character anywhere — if so, just `[[:upper:]]` should be sufficient, and if not, please add more examples that clarify.

Comment: Thanks, `^[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]-]*$`works!

Comment: I see you updated the question, and now, I do not understand why `aNaTOLa` should be matched. If starts with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
Word.where.not("content ~ ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]-]*$")
```

Here, `^[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]-]*$` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:upper:]]` - any uppercase letter
- `[[:alpha:]-]*` - zero or more letters or hyphens
- `$` - end of string.

If there can be any char but whitespace in the "word" replace `[[:alpha:]-]` with `\S` or `[^[:space:]]`.

If you do not care what kind of chars there are after the uppercase letter, use

```rb
Word.where.not("content ~ ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[[:upper:]]")
```

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for your help. The best solution is `Word.where.not("content ~ ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[.[:upper:].]")`

Comment: @nico_lrx Looks like you do not care about what comes after the first uppercase letter, so use `Word.where.not("content ~ ?", "([0-9])|([.,?!])|^[[:upper:]]")`